# Developer Story warning won't go away

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, developer-story

A warning badge keeps showing on my "Developer Story" tab that states: "You are open, but not actively looking for a job. We need more information before sending you matches."

[image: warning dialogue]

When I click either the "Developer Story" tab or look at my "Job Match Preferences", nowhere does it prompt me nor show me where exactly any new information is needed. As far as I can tell I've completed all the information to the fullest extent.

There are 2 orange, what look like warnings under my "Job Match Preferences" for which I would assume might be contributing to the problem but the information is filled in:

[image: sub-warning one]
[image: sub-warning two]

For reference, here is my [developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/aaronwilliamson).

How do I make this notification either go away or provide the cryptic information it's asking from me? It's rather annoying, it's not very clear, and apparently it says I won't be sent any matches until these phantom errors are fixed. I emailed Stack Overflow and they suggested that I post my question here.

Comment: What is your "Job search status," - open but not actively looking, actively looking?  Are the remainder of the fields beneath that fully filled out?

Comment: Under my "Job Search Preferences" my status is "I'm open, but not actively looking". For match preferences: "Where I'd like to work", "Developer types", "Seniority", "Minimum annual compensation" and "Full time permanent" are all filled out. For "Technologies", "Tech you like working with" is filled out and finally for "Contact information", my phone number is filled in.

Comment: Try selecting an industry or two ("Software Developement," for example) and consider adding a "Would prefer not to work with," just to test it out?  EDIT: Nevermind, I see you added a screenshot of this, now.  Hmm.

Comment: Good suggestion but I tried that, I edited my my original question with more relevant screenshots.

Comment: This went away when I filled my developer story with around 5 cards with detailed information.

Comment: I mean, I consider mine pretty filled in. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2981132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a small bug in the logic we use to determine whether or not the requirements sidebar panel should be shown. That bug only affected users who had previously created a Careers CV at some point, which seems to be your case. I have fixed the bug and now you should be able to check what is missing on your profile in a nice orange sidebar box :)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the feedback! The bit we're missing for you is the 150 character description for a work or education item. Your current work item has 140 characters - which is close!

On your Developer Story you should see the side panel warning which provides more detail about what your missing:

[image]

But it appears you're not currently seeing the prompt, which is a bug :) We're looking into it now and will update shortly.

Comment: Thanks Kit! Looks like you and @rla4 found and fixed it. The phantom orange box is no longer phantom.